# onReceiveAd issue, unrecognised class

Tags: android, adview

I am running the following inside my OnCreate method:

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
            slideEnabler = true;
        }
    });
```

In the above code, the compiler is having issues with the term "Ad" in onReceiveAd(Ad ad).

It does not recognise this term despite the fact that exactly 100% of all examples I have seen regarding this method using that exact temrinology.  The compiler is suggesting that I create the class 'Ad'.

What have I done wrong?   Why does it work for everyone else?

Comment: compiler is correct. What is "Ad" by the way? You should implement that class.

Comment: Then why does every single example on the net about this method use the exact code I have posted above?  Is everyone on the internet wrong? Or is the compiler wrong?  I couldn't work out was was wrong with this so I used the answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why all the examples in every post on the internet about this are wrong, but I am assuming that onReceiveAd is simply old code that is not relevant any more.   With that in mind, I got exactly what I was after by using a different command:

```
 mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            slideEnabler = true;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps someone else who is confused by this issue.